# Change XLS cell value in Linux CLI without breaking format

Tags: python, excel, linux, libreoffice-calc

I am attempting to automate edits to a cell from a pre-provided spreadsheet. I need to adjust a single value in a single cell without breaking the formatting.

I have tried pyexcel, xlutils and openpyxl to no avail; they can change data but break the formatting of the document.

I have also tried placing dummy text in the file and using sed to change that;

```
sed -i 's/changethisvalue/thisischangevalue/g' file-name.xls
```

I find that this simple replacement breaks the formatting of the document when I attempt to open it in LibreCalc.

My question is; does an XLS document contain specific formatting data that's sensitive to cell content, and is there a way to 'hack' this to work?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you've tried?

Comment: Have you tried search/replace within Excel or is there some restriction we need to know about here?

Comment: I've tried using the various libraries in their different ways to open up an XLS document, change a field, then save it however they do not keep the formatting of the document which is quintessential.

Sed will adjust the value I need, but corrupt the document.

TheZeke; because that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: XLS is a binary file format, you can't just replace text.

Comment: I'm aware that I can't just replace text, but I'd like to have a script which fills out my timesheets for me and sends them, because I keep forgetting lol